# Initialize object from Initialized object by DI in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have common DI usage in my ASP.NET Core application.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{  
     services.AddScoped(sp => new UserContext(new DbContextOptionsBuilder().UseNpgsql(configuration["User"]).Options));
     services.AddScoped(sp => new ConfigContext(new DbContextOptionsBuilder().UseNpgsql(configuration["Config"]).Options));         
}
```

In `ConfigContext` exists method `GetUserString` which returns `connectionString` to `UserContext`.
And I need `AddScoped UserContext` with `connectionString` from `ConfigContext`
when applying to `UserContext`.

Comment: Can the connection string vary on a per-request basis (different user)?

Comment: Yes, can differ depending on the logic in the configcontext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register the service with an implementation factory, and resolve another service inside the factory, using the IServiceProvider provided as an argument.

In this way, you are using one service to help instantiate another.

```
public class UserContext
{
    public UserContext(string config)
    {
        // config used here
    }
}

public class ConfigContext
{
    public string GetConfig()
    {
        return "config";
    }
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...

    services.AddScoped<ConfigContext>();

    services.AddScoped<UserContext>(sp => 
        new UserContext(sp.GetService<ConfigContext>().GetConfig()));
}
```